# iPhone - adding new group to class folder - import not detecting

Tags: iphone, cocoa, iphone-sdk-3.0

I hope you can help with that.

OK i have created new group/folder under Classes - Libs: Classes/Libs and have created class there Msg.h

now I am trying to import it into my RootViewController

```
#import "Libs/Msg.h"
```

but I am getting an error:

```
Libs/Msg.h = no such file or directory
```

what should i Do ?

cheers,
/marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as it turns out, the Libs is not required just

```
#import "Msg.h"
```

is enaugh even if its in folder level down.

thanks

Comment: Groups in Xcode and folders in Finder are not related. Groups show up tan in Xcode; folders you add to your Xcode project show up blue (and, importantly, Xcode considers the folder to be a single object, to be [usually] copied all at once—it does not think about anything inside the folder). When you import a header using a path like `Libs/Msg.h`, the preprocessor will look for a Msg.h file in a Libs *folder*. Since you created a group, not a folder, no such folder exists, hence it not finding the file.

Answer (score 0):

What path is your RootViewController in? If you give a path in import, it must be relative to the current file. Also check the case of both directory and file; Mac OS X is case-insensitive, but Xcode and iPhone are not.